# How to create a cshtml file in visual studio 2010 , MVC2 with dot net framework 4.0?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, razor

I a using visual studio 2010.Is it possible to create a cshtml file from view since in my installed version i can only create aspx file.
Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `cshtml` is just text files you always can just change extension =)

Right click on new file (any type, you can create just cs file) in `View` foulder -> Rename -> set `.cshtml` extension.

Comment: @ teo van knot. i mean the file becomes unusable then.

Comment: To add razor syntax support for VS 2010 you can install [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2011/01/12/how-to-get-razor-syntax-support-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx).

Comment: what do you mean - unusable? No syntax highlighting?

Comment: I tried to do what you told me but it reports that file will become unusable then.

Comment: it tolds that file **CAN** become unusable. But if you have installed razor syntax highlighting everything will be ok.

Comment: @ teo van kot. Is there any way to install razor syntax seperately?. since when i tried to install mvc 3 from web installer it reports that " unable to install since sytem requireents are not met".

Comment: i've already told you - [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2011/01/12/how-to-get-razor-syntax-support-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx) all you need.